# Streak win loss pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I trying to count streak of sign in dataframe but not working to sum values when it same sign.

```
df['win'] = np.sign(df['log'])
df['steak']= 0

df.loc[(df['win']!=df['win'].shift()  ),'steak'] = df['win']
df.loc[(df['win']==df['win'].shift()  ),'steak'] = df['steak'] + df['win']
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmQhG.png)

how to work with it?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: https://puu.sh/GKoJY.png i need run with consecutive w/l if loss -1 and win +1 when streak sum value -1 +(-1) or 1 +(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#df['win'] = np.sign(df['log'])
blocks = df['win'].ne(df['win'].shift()).cumsum()
df['consecutive WL'] = df['win'].groupby(blocks).cumsum()
```